# Change Channel/Bot NAME and Telegram search results Cache

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, channel

When we change the name of a Telegram channel;
And we search for the previous name in Telegram, it still shows this channel in Telegram results.

I want to know that it means that Telegram caches the results of previous searches?

Or does it actually cache and keep the previous name of the channel?

And how long is this cache valid?

Is there any detailed technical documentation about this?

Example:

- Rename a Telegram channel (or bot).
- Then search for the previous name.
- Even if there are no similar terms in the old and new name, it will be displayed in the search results (with the terms of the old name) of that channel.
- But it is not known how long it will be like this?

Comment: We are looking to optimize Telegram search results.